Unable to install calico network on droplet with kubectl command
I am trying this
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
Error:

root@k8-master:~# kubectl apply -f calico.yaml error: error validating
"calico.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get
"https://139.59.14.254:6443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp
139.59.14.254:6443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I tried --validate=false as well but still get the same error. Couldn't any info on web for this. Can anyone help?
